# the constructor Item(int ,String ,double) is undefined

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to insert a row of a table into oracle database  eclipse is showing this error the constructor Item(int ,String ,double) is undefined

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.testing.cache.Item;

public class InsertItem {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration config=new Configuration();
        SessionFactory factory=config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        Item item=new Item( 1001,"sony",9000);
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(item);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

this is my another class

```
public class Item {
    private int itemId;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Item()
    {
    }

    public Item(int itemID)
    {
        this.itemId=itemId;
    }

    public Item(int itemID,String name,double price)
    {
        this.itemId=itemId;
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Item["+itemId+","+name+","+price+"]";
    }    
}
```

I'm trying to insert a row of a table into oracle database  eclipse is showing this error `the constructor Item(int ,String ,double) is undefined`

Comment: try clean compile

Answer (score 4):

You have imported the incorrect `Item` class,

```
import org.hibernate.testing.cache.Item;
```

You should be using the class which you have created.